# Include only specific targets from another makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have two adjacent directories `A` and `B`.
In `A` is `makefile_a`, and in `B` is `makefile_b`.

`makefile_b` does some preprocessing whose output is later used by the targets of `makefile_a`. So I would like to define certain targets in `makefile_a` to depend on targets in `makefile_b`.

Normally I would do this with, in `makefile_a`, the line `include ../B/makefile_b`, as described in make's documentation on [include](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html).
However, **I don't want to pollute the namespace of `makefile_a` with all the targets defined in `makefile_b`; I only want to import the one target in question**. For example, there are targets with identical names defined in both `makefile_a` and `makefile_b` which would clash. For that and other reasons I only want to import the one target in question, not all of them.

How can this be done? I don't see any way to do that explained in the documentation. I considered making a second makefile in `B`, something like `makefile_b_export`, to be included by both `makefile_a` and `makefile_b`, and contain only the targets that I wish to include in `makefile_b`, but that would be a hack and presents its own set of issues, like how do the exported targets depend on those defined in `makefile_b` without creating an import cycle.

Is there a proper way to handle this scenario using `make`? What do you suggest would be the cleanest way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to include just "part" of a file, or just "some" targets.

You can either take the content that's shared in put it into a separate file such as `shared_b.mk` and then add `include shared_b.mk` to both the makefiles.

Or, you can use `ifdef` to skip including the non-shared content if a variable is set, then before you include `makefile_b` you can set that variable.

Or, instead of including the makefiles you can have `makefile_a` build the specific target(s) in `makefile_b` by having a rule that invokes make recursively in that subdirectory:

```
.PHONY: targ_b1 targ_b2
targ_b1 targ_b2:
        $(MAKE) -C ../b $@
```

or whatever.

Comment: Option #3 there (recursively invoking make in the directory ../B with phone target targ_b1 or targ_b2) looks about perfect. Thank you!